# What's the easiest way to rename the columns of a DataGridView showing a List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, whose DataSource I am setting to a `List<T>`. `T` in this case is a class with a property called `Foo`, whose header I want to show as `Foo bar`.

If it was a datatable, I could just change the query:

```
select Foo as [Foo bar] from Baz
```

But with something like this, where I'm setting the DataGridView's DataSource to a `List<Baz>`:

```
public class Baz {
   public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I can't rename "`Foo`" to "`Foo bar`" because it contains spaces. Do I have to rename the DataGridViewColumn manually?

The most awesome thing would be if I could use class decorators, something like this:

```
public class Baz {
   [DataGridViewColumnTitle("Foo bar")]
   public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

But I as far as I can see, nothing like that exists in the standard library.

What's my best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DisplayName("Foo bar")]
```

(in the System.ComponentModel namespace; [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx))

Comment: Beautiful! I knew it had to exist :)